# Potential problems with a design that overloads << operator for logging

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging

I wanted to write a class that could be used similar to how `std::cout` uses the `<<` operator.  I wanted to be able to get a mutex at the beginning of the segment of code that used a series of `<<` operators and have that mutex released at the end of the statement.

For example:

```
logger << "Information blah "<< 1;
```

Without a lock, things could get interleaved between "Information blah " and 1 in multithreaded operation.

Is there some major problem with the design of these classes to do this?  I know there are tons of logging libraries, I am just playing with a way to maintain a mutex at the beginning of a series of `<<` operators and release the mutex at the end.

```
class Logger;

class LockedLogger
{
    public:
        LockedLogger(Logger & logger):logger_(logger),lock_(new std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(logger.outputMutex_)) {};

        template<typename T>
        const LockedLogger & operator <<(T t) const{//Logging Code.}    
    private:
        LockedLogger & logger_;
        std::shared_ptr<std::lock_guard<std::mutex> > lock_;
};


class Logger
{
    public:
        Logger();

        template<typename T>
        LockedLogger operator << (T t){return LockedLogger(*this) << t;}

    private:
        std::mutex outputMutex_;

        friend class LockedLogger;
};
Logger logger;
```

Comment: Yes. There's probably easier ways to implement a logger, of course.

Comment: Well, does it work? If not, what is the problem? If so, you should be on [codereview.se].

Comment: It *seems* to work fine (I find that sometimes things that appear to _work_ do not actually _work_ in some way).  Thanks, I did not know that Code Review existed.  Will post there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to use locked logger, then you will stall other threads while one thread is logging and possibly preparing the to be logged information/strings.

Instead, why don't you figure out a way to prepare the to be logged information/string without a lock (e.g., into a function/scope local or thread local object/string) and then log the whole information/string at once, keeping the synchronised section as short as possible.

Comment: It is easy to do that: I just need to keep concating the items and then get the lock write and release the lock in the when the LockedLogger is going out of scope.


Besides for that, are there any problems with the << operator returning a new class that lives only for the length of the series of << statements?

Comment: @rileymat: No; in fact that's a common pattern. You're talking about proxy objects.

Comment: Sometimes, it's possible to signal/queue off a pointer to the object to a separate logger thread and later call a serialise() method when it arrives.  That takes nearly all the load off the originating thread and reduces the lock time to that required to copy a pointer.  Sure, this is not always possible due lifetimes, mutability etc, but I thought I should mention it anyway, if only to annoy Loungers.